# Timeout of the producer confirmation mechanism

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a question, that is, how to set the time of the producer's message acknowledgement mechanism?
The rabbitMQ producer creates the good news and sends it successfully. My question is: does the producer validation mechanism have a timeout to prove that it has failed?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#template-confirms

You can wait on the future in the correlation data with a timeout...

> ...

> Starting with version 2.1, the `CorrelationData` object has a `ListenableFuture` that you can use to get the result, instead of using a `ConfirmCallback` on the template. The following example shows how to configure a CorrelationData instance:

```java
CorrelationData cd1 = new CorrelationData();
this.templateWithConfirmsEnabled.convertAndSend("exchange", queue.getName(), "foo", cd1);
assertTrue(cd1.getFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).isAck());
```

> ...